# FFMPEG - COPY MKV to MP4 but add 2.0 Stream

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, mp4, matroska, audio-conversion

Morning All,

Using FFMPEG currently just to re-container UHD MKV into MP4 with...

```
ffmpeg -i File1.mkv -c:v copy -c:a copy -strict -2 File1.mp4
```

But these MKV only have TrueHD or DTS-HD which is fine when playing to my theatre room as it passes through to my receiver, but my TV doesn't do a great job of downmixing the surround to 2.0. So I want to add an extra track at 2.0.

I'm not overly clever with this stuff and generally google everything.. So is there something I can add to my script to create and add a 2.0 audio stream to my final mp4??

TIA
JB

Answer (score 0):

We may use `aresample` filter for converting DTS-HD to stereo, as described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/594741/how-to-use-ffmpeg-to-downmix-5-1-dts-hd-ma-or-dolby-truehd-to-stereo-aac-with-do).
For adding a second audio channel we may use `-filter_complex` with stream mapping.

---

Start by creating a sample `File1.mkv` input file (for testing).
The example is based on the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60808171/ffmpeg-create-blank-video-file-with-multichannel-audio).

```
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=25 -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=5.1:sample_rate=48000 -c:v libx264 -crf 17 -strict -2 -c:a dts -t 10 File1.mkv
```

Note the `anullsrc` is silent (used only for testing).

---

Command for converting to stereo and adding the stereo as second audio stream:

```
ffmpeg -y -i File1.mkv -filter_complex "[0:a]aresample=matrix_encoding=dplii[a]" -map:v 0:v -map:a:0 0:a -map:a:1 "[a]" -c:v copy -c:a:0 copy -c:a:1 aac -ac 2 -strict -2 File1.mp4
```

---

Checking the output with MediaInfo:

```
General
Complete name                            : File1.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
...


Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
...


Audio #1
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : DTS
Format/Info                              : Digital Theater Systems
Codec ID                                 : mp4a-A9
Duration                                 : 10 s 5 ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 1 413 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 6 channels
Channel layout                           : C L R Ls Rs LFE
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                               : 93.750 FPS (512 SPF)
Bit depth                                : 16 bits
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 1.69 MiB (96%)
Default                                  : Yes
Alternate group                          : 1

Audio #2
ID                                       : 3
Format                                   : AAC LC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
Codec ID                                 : mp4a-40-2
Duration                                 : 10 s 6 ms
Source duration                          : 10 s 27 ms
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 2 278 b/s
Maximum bit rate                         : 128 kb/s / 128 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel layout                           : L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                               : 46.875 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 2.78 KiB (0%)
Source stream size                       : 2.79 KiB (0%)
Default                                  : Yes
Alternate group                          : 2
mdhd_Duration                            : 10005
```

---

Note:
My answer regards only the conversion and mapping syntax - there is no guarantees regarding the quality.